# How to make POST request in android using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 in my android code. I have started making some server calls using the same and now I'm stuck on the POSt request used in retrofit.

What I want is to make a POST request and the data I want to send is something like ["1","2","3","4"]

I almost tried out all the ways but no luck.

Comment: *I almost tried out all the ways* ... It's is hard to belive... If it would be true why you didn't share with us with what had you tried so far?

Comment: Ok so you want me to post all the code here what I have tried so far. So for your info, I have tried passing List<Integer> directly in the interface with @Body annotations. Also by passing RequestBody in the method of interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few tutorials out there, but I've knocked up a very quick example for you, excuse the slightly rushed code etc, hopefully you get the idea.

1. Your rest interface:

   ```
   public interface MyRetrofit {
   @POST("/users")
   Call<MyResponse> postUser(@Body MyRequest body);}
   ```
2. Your retrofit create

   ```
   OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl("http://little-silence-8649.getsandbox.com")
           .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build();

   apiInterface = retrofit.create(MyRetrofit.class);
   ```
3. The call

   ```
   MyRequest req = new MyRequest();
   req.setName("Kermit");
   Call<MyResponse> task = apiInterface.postUser(req);
   task.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Success");
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
              Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", throwable);
          }
   });
   ```

This should all be pretty self explanatory. You create your interface which defines all your REST calls in step one. Then in step two you create an instance of retrofit passing in an ok http client and a gson converter. The gson converter converts your requests to json.

Then lastly the call. I create a request, this is just a pojo and pass this to by retrofit api. We use enqueue because we're on the main thread and we want retrofit to handle the networking on a new thread. When it's complete retrofit passes us back an onResponse or onFailure.

Hope it helps.

P.S This example uses [Sandbox](https://getsandbox.com/) which is an amazing test tool for REST interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I have tried this type by creating POJO but this doesn't work..